# Content slide down on top of page?

Tags: jquery, slide

I have been searching for a while but did not find something I like ... I want a slidedown as shown on https://www.backyard-shop.de/ (see the arrow on the top of the page). Once its clicked, it slides down a content area.

I know it can be build with jQuery, but I was hoping there is something ready out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's almost an out of the box function of jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Scroll down to the examples, there is an complete functional script.